# LESS extend doesn't seem to work right

Tags: css, less

I am new to LESS and I've tried many versions to get this, I am trying to extend a few classes into one, but can't even get one to work. I have:

```
.header{
     .newHeader{
         &:extend(.newColor);
     }
     .secondHeader{
         &:extend(.newColor);
     }
 }
 .newColor{
     color: black;
 }
```

So the expected output would be:

```
.newColor, .header .newHeader, .header .secondHeader{
     color: black;
}
```

Comment: less wont combine things like that.

Comment: on their site their demo looks just like this, so there is no way to generate classes with the same property only into one line?

Comment: do you have a link?

Comment: http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature and if you go to there ( try it ) section and copy out the code, it works there, click on extend  when you go to that link

Comment: now this is weird, it works in my project even though it is giving me an error: Missing a property name before the colon (:) in the ( property : value ) declaration, i'm using visual studio less compiler